# Oracle - Handle empty resultset on IF THEN ELSE statement

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

which should be the IF condition when the variable assignation results from an empty resultset?

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function get_values
     ( chv_input IN varchar2 )
     RETURN varchar2
IS
     chv_output varchar2(100);

  BEGIN

select 'value'
    into chv_output
from dual where 1=2; 

IF chv_output is null THEN --this condition is not working

    chv_output := 'null';

ELSE
     chv_output := 'not null';

END IF;

  RETURN chv_output;

END;

--select 1, get_values('112') from dual
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
  chv_output := 'null';
```

Comment: great. I used just after the select. Like this: select 'value' into chv_output from dual where 1=2; EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
NULL;